# Can't uninstall app says already uninstalled

Tags: uninstallation

I am working on a game an I decided to change name of it. Now I can't uninstall or install my game. When I try to install it says it is already installed and when I try to uninstall it shows something like this (My game is at the bottom of the list):

[image: Not Installed]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with turning to guest mod which is new on Xperia with lollipop update, then I uninstalled it from guest user. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simple glitch! Try some troubleshooting...

1. Turn off developer settings.
2. Install ES file explorer. Go to App manager in the Es file explorer.
3. Try to uninstall the app from that app manager.
   IF u still cant do that?
4. Delete the app directory(your own app) & restart the phone.

Comment: I have solved the problem in another way I will share the answer soon. Thanks for help